# Storing a query in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

This is the case: A webshop in which I want to configure which items should be listed in the sjop based on a set of parameters.
I want this to be configurable, because that allows me to experiment with different parameters also change their values easily.

I have a Product collection that I want to query based on multiple parameters. 
A couple of these are found here:

within product:

```
"delivery" : {
    "maximum_delivery_days" : 30,
    "average_delivery_days" : 10,
    "source" : 1,
    "filling_rate" : 85,
    "stock" : 0
}
```

but also other parameters exist.

An example of such query to decide whether or not to include a product could be:

```
"$or" : [
        {
            "delivery.stock" : 1
        },
        {
            "$or" : [
                    {
                            "$and" : [
                                    {
                                            "delivery.maximum_delivery_days" : {
                                                    "$lt" : 60
                                            }
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "delivery.filling_rate" : {
                                                    "$gt" : 90
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                            "$and" : [
                                    {
                                            "delivery.maximum_delivery_days" : {
                                                    "$lt" : 40
                                            }
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "delivery.filling_rate" : {
                                                    "$gt" : 80
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    },
                    {
                            "$and" : [
                                    {
                                            "delivery.delivery_days" : {
                                                    "$lt" : 25
                                            }
                                    },
                                    {
                                            "delivery.filling_rate" : {
                                                    "$gt" : 70
                                            }
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            ]
        }
]
```

Now to make this configurable, I need to be able to handle boolean logic, parameters and values. 
So, I got the idea, since such query itself is JSON, to store it in Mongo and have my Java app retrieve it. 
Next thing is using it in the filter (e.g. find, or whatever) and work on the corresponding selection of products.
The advantage of this approach is that I can actually analyse the data and the effectiveness of the query outside of my program.

I would store it by name in the database. E.g.

```
{ 
    "name": "query1",
    "query": { the thing printed above starting with "$or"... }
}
```

using:

```
db.queries.insert({
    "name" : "query1",
    "query": { the thing printed above starting with "$or"... }
})
```

Which results in:

```
2016-03-27T14:43:37.265+0200 E QUERY    Error: field names cannot start with $ [$or]
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at DBCollection._validateForStorage (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:161:19)
    at DBCollection._validateForStorage (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:165:18)
    at insert (src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:646:20)
    at DBCollection.insert (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:243:18)
    at (shell):1:12 at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:161
```

But I CAN STORE it using Robomongo, but not always. Obviously I am doing something wrong. But I have NO IDEA what it is.
If it fails, and I create a brand new collection and try again, it succeeds. Weird stuff that goes beyond what I can comprehend.

But when I try updating values in the "query", changes are not going through. Never. Not even sometimes.
I can however create a new object and discard the previous one. So, the workaround is there.

```
db.queries.update(
    {"name": "query1"},
    {"$set": { 
            ... update goes here ...
        }
    }
)
```

doing this results in:

```
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 52,
                "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$or' in 'action.$or' is not valid for storage."
        }
})
```

seems pretty close to the other message above.

Needles to say, I am pretty clueless about what is going on here, so I hope some of the wizzards here are able to shed some light on the matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message contains the important info you need to consider:

> QUERY Error: field names cannot start with $

Since you are trying to store a query (or part of one) in a document, you'll end up with attribute names that contain mongo operator keywords (such as `$or`, `$ne`, `$gt`). [The mongo documentation actually references this exact scenario](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) - emphasis added

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and **they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $)**...

---

I wouldn't trust 3rd party applications such as Robomongo in these instances. I suggest debugging/testing this issue directly in the mongo shell.

My suggestion would be to store an escaped version of the query in your document as to not interfere with reserved operator keywords. You can use the available `JSON.stringify(my_obj);` to encode your partial query into a string and then parse/decode it when you choose to retrieve it later on: `JSON.parse(escaped_query_string_from_db)`

Comment: So.. are you suggesting to store an stringified object as string instead of the object itself? You are also writing: "I suggest debugging/testing this issue directly in the mongo shell." How? Finally, (to give a little more info) the objects that do get stored using Robomongo are available as normal objects and after retrieval can be passed to a query by my Java program. So, these do actually work.

Comment: Yes - I'm suggesting that you store the data in an escaped format (stringified). This will prevent the `$` characters from interfering with mongo keywords.

Comment: With regard to what I said about debugging/testing - I mean that you should do the testing that this method indeed works for your case [directly in the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/client/) - inside the command line - and not through a 3rd party interface (Robomongo).

Comment: I am still wondering a bit about the approach. Should I do this using Javascript? Probably yes. BTW here is a screendump of the objects that got inserted using Robo. https://www.dropbox.com/s/verrv8l7s7dfbi9/Screenshot%202016-03-27%2016.15.09.png?dl=0

Comment: Depending on your application, you could use Javascript to escape the string...although almost any language you use should have a similar way to escape/encode strings so that they don't interfere with other functionalities...

Comment: Again - just because Robomongo is able to decipher/insert the documents - it would still require you to validate the functionality through your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still I am surprised that some of the objects were succesfully stored at all (and available as objects without any conversion)

Comment: I think that the results you see (sometimes it works other times it doesn't) should be enough for you to re-evaluate the method you are using. Rather than trying to figure out why/when something works - write your application/logic in such a way that the inconsistencies don't exist.
Also you are very welcome! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of storing the query as a JSON object in MongoDB is not viable.

You could potentially store your query logic and fields in MongoDB, but you have to have an external app build the query with the proper MongoDB syntax.

MongoDB queries contain operators, and some of those have special characters in them.

There are rules for mongoDB filed names. These rules do not allow for special characters. 
Look here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

The probable reason you can sometimes successfully create the doc using Robomongo is because Robomongo is transforming your query into a string and properly escaping the special characters as it sends it to MongoDB.

This also explains why your attempt to update them never works. You tried to create a document, but instead created something that is a string object, so your update conditions are probably not retrieving any docs.

Comment: I've had issues in the past with Robomongo and the way it handles/parses dates (Date objects vs ISODate) - I wouldn't be surprised if they were doing some sort of trickery to the query strings it receives...

Comment: I am a but puzzled about what the API's and Robo do. Because as mentioned in the other thread, objects that got stored are definitely usable from my Java and can be passed in as a query parameter (e.g. find(the query parameter)). What's more because Robo also presents these objects in their browser as regular JSON, there could be an additional parsing step in between. But this then also applies to the Java API, because the same retrieved object in Java works as parameter in the find.

Comment: It is still weird. Maybe there are still some bits I am missing. Example: doing `db.queries.insert({
    "name" : "stock",
    "value" : "\"$or\" : [{\"delivery.stock\":1}]"
})` in the shell works, but also Robo sees it as a string in that case...

Comment: Well puzzled or not. I think both of you are right. Even if it succeeds, I should not count on it, because it seems unsupported behaviour I am relying on. Which is a silly thing to do. I will try using javascript with serialize to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your approach.

In following query

```
db.queries.insert({
   "name" : "query1",
   "query": { the thing printed above starting with "$or"... }
})
```

a valid JSON expects key, value pair. here in `"query"` you are storing an object without a `key`. You have two options. either store query as text or create another key inside curly braces.

Second problem is, you are storing `query` values without wrapping in quotes. All string values must be wrapped in quotes.

so your final document should appear as

```
db.queries.insert({
    "name" : "query1",
    "query": 'the thing printed above starting with "$or"... '
})
```

Now try, it should work.

Comment: I believe that `{ the thing printed above starting with "$or"... }
` is just a place holder for a bigger query object. This string was just given as an example...

Comment: You may be right. even string contains $, it must be quoted to store in MongoDB.

Comment: Ah... now I understand your @Saleem comment )

Answer (score 0):

Obviously my attempt to store a query in mongo the way I did was foolish as became clear from the answers from both @bigdatakid and @lix. So what I finally did was this: I altered the naming of the fields to comply to the mongo requirements.

E.g. instead of $or I used _$or etc. and instead of using a . inside the name I used a #. Both of which I am replacing in my Java code.

This way I can still easily try and test the queries outside of my program. In my Java program I just change the names and use the query. Using just 2 lines of code. It simply works now. Thanks guys for the suggestions you made.

```
String documentAsString = query.toJson().replaceAll("_\\$", "\\$").replaceAll("#", ".");
    Object q = JSON.parse(documentAsString);
```

Comment: So you still managed to run the query from your mongo collection with this solution? You should mark this as the right answer.

Comment: thanks for the message. I marked answer #1 because that was essentially correct. I just used that info for my workaround here.